# How do you reset a “$timeout”, and disable a “$watch()”?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

How do you reset a “$timeout”, and disable a “$watch()”?

```
var customTimeout = $timeout(function () {
  // arbitrary code
}, 55);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to both is assigning the result of the function to a variable.

To cleanup the timeout, just “.cancel()” it:

```
$timeout.cancel(customTimeout);
```

The same applies to “$interval()”.

To disable a watch, just call it.

> .$watch() returns a deregistration function that we store to a variable

```
var deregisterWatchFn = $rootScope.$watch(‘someGloballyAvailableProperty’, function (newVal) {
  if (newVal) {
    // we invoke that deregistration function, to disable the watch
    deregisterWatchFn();
    ...
  }
});
```